# Spring Querying DateTime by Date

Tags: java, spring, date, datetime, spring-data

I am fairly new to spring so maybe I am missing the wrong terminology and that is the reason why my searches brought nothing up.

The Query I am looking for should Take a parent object and remove all Child objects where a timestamp is not of a specific date.

```
Parent Id field1 field2

Child: Id parentId field 1 timestamp (datetime)
```

I tried several different approaches but nothing seems to work.

Alternatively I could try something like:

```
FindAllChildsByIdAndTimestamp(int id, Date date)
```

And fill a empty Parent with the data. But event hat does not work.
Any Idea what i am doing wrong? 
Best and Thank you

Comment: What about a JPQL bulk delete along the lines of 'delete from Child c where c.parent = :parent and c.someDate != :someDate'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by seperating the two requests.

```
public interface ChildRepository extends CrudRepository<Child, Serializable> {
List<child> findAllBytimeStampBetweenAndParent(Date dayBegin, Date dayEnd, Parent parent);
```

And then attributed it to the parent

```
Parent parent = this.getById(id);

    // Convert Date Type
    DateTime dayTimeEnd = new DateTime(date);
    dayTimeEnd = dayTimeEnd.plusHours(23);
    dayTimeEnd = dayTimeEnd.plusMinutes(55);
    Date dayEnd = dayTimeEnd.toDate();

    // Get all Tracking Data of this Date
    List<Child> ChildList = this.childRepository.findAllBytimeStampBetweenAndParent(date, dayEnd, parent);
```

as an alternative i could have used direct queries. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to bring a parent into this. All you need to do is to create a query on a child table and generate a query on that table with where clause would be parentId is  and timestamp is . You mentioned that you are using Spring (which version BTW?) but didn't say what do you use to access your DB (Spring Data, Hibernate, JPA, JBC?) Also which DB and which version? I will give you example in Hibernate:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Child.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("parentId", yourParentId))
                .add(Restrictions.gt("timestamp", date1))
                .add(Restrictions.le("timestamp", date2))
                .list();
```

date1 is midnight of your day and date2 is midnight of the following day. This should give you the list of your children

Comment: This is Hibernate code so I am not sure  how it is relevant here.

Comment: OP didn't specify what tool is used for querying. So I explained in principle what the solution might be and gave Hibernate as an example